# Rails: mongodb error when using $lt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

this code return an error

```
db[:zips].find(city: {$lt: 'd'}).limit(2).to_a.each{|r| pp r}
```

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input

However, this code works well

```
db[:zips].find(city: {:$lt=> 'd'}).limit(2).to_a.each{|r| pp r}
```

Why can not use :$lt like the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the JSON-like `{key: value}` syntax in this case , because the key starts with `$`. Either use the older hash syntax or, since ruby 2.2,

```
{'$lt': 'd'}
```

I couldn't find a reference for when quoting is required (emojis are OK for example) - I suspect you would have to delve into the ruby source for this.

Comment: Thanks you, really helpful.